# Operations with stochastic big and little o

Tags: asymptotics, weak-convergence

I have a question related to stochastic little/big o notation. Consider a sequence of real-valued random variables $\{X_n\}_n$.

Is it correct $O_p(1)+X_no_p(1)=O_p(1)$
?

Why?

I know that $O_p(1)+o_p(1)=O_p(1)$ but I'm wondering what happens if $o_p(1)$ is premultiplied by $X_n$.

Comment: what's $O_p(1)$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation

Comment: Is $X_n$ bounded? And what are the asymptotics taken with regard to?

Comment: I don't have assumptions of $X_n$ and the asymptotics are wrto $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Then, no. For instance, $X_n$ could be a r.v. with $X_n = 2^n$ a.s.: then $X_n\cdot o(1)$ could be anything that is $o(2^n)$.

Comment: Under which conditions would my statement hold?